# ¿Escuchar un puerto?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, servidor, consola

estoy escuchando un puerto con el siguiente comando en terminal

```
while true; do nc -k -l -p pppp -s xx.xxx.xx.xx; done
```

donde pppp es mi puerto y xx... es la IP.

No recuerdo como enviar un mensaje a esa IP con ese Puerto, para poder "escucharlo" o verlo desde el lado servidor, creí que era con nmap pero parece que no.

¿Me pueden ayudar a recordarlo?

Comment: Hola Carlos. Igual la documentacion puede refrescarte la memoria. Aqui las preguntas son sobre problemas concretos tras haber intentado algo. Investiga, prueba y si tienes errores, preguntalos editando la pregunta y siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo